# Global access to objects; When to use Domain Driven Design Repositories

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I've been following DDD principles (following the Eric Evans book on the topic) however I recently started re-reading the book and noticed that I appear to have strayed from one of the principles for `repositories`...

> "For each type of object that needs global access, create an object
>   that can provide the illusion of an in-memory collection..."

I've strayed from this in that I create a `repository` for **every** `aggregate` and have found that this has suited me well. Even when an `aggregate` is itself associated with another `aggregate` it's a simple matter of referring to the associated aggregate's `repository`  during creation of the `entity` (usually inside a factory).

The benefits of doing this that I've found are when performing operations such as caching in my repositories. It also really simplifies the divide between object creation/persistence and the domain.

Can somebody give me an example of where this "Global access" is not appropriate to help me understand where I've gone wrong.

Comment: The global access means only aggregate root can be referenced by other part of the system while local entity cannot. This aims to protect invariants. if some one wants to modify an local entity , he/she must do this by retrieve the aggregate and use it to modify the entity, therefore the invariants (provided by the aggregate) is garunteed.

Comment: +1 "global access" is what defines aggregate roots, as opposed to simple entities which only their root has access to. Also, you mention aggregates containing aggregates. This is much atypical in DDD, if not discouraged.

Comment: Could you clarify you question a little bit more? for example, what do you mean by "where I've gone wrong"? Any code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using wrong terms... Aggregate can't contain other aggregate. You probably have an association between those aggregates.

In any case, every aggregate should have repository, otherwise you are doing something wrong. Also it's better to use repository to load aggregate instead of association from other aggregate. If you keep your association (probably because your ORM makes it easy) you didn't split aggregates completely.

Comment: Thanks @gseric, I take on board your comment regarding composition and agree that there can only be `association` between `aggregates`. I've edited the post appropriately.